# Vector calculus vs Vector analysis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, terminology, book-recommendation

I was just wondering, is vector analysis the same as vector calculus? What about multivariable calculus? Because my multivariable calculus book (which I assume is the same as vector calculus?) covers topics like Lagrange multipliers, but the Schaum's outline book I have for vector analysis doesn't have this topic (and a few others) and is much thinner.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is like asking which fruits the textbook author likes to eat. The names for the areas are just a guide as to what the contents are, and clearly Schaum didn't think people need/should know Lagrange multipliers (but it's one of the most useful tools!)

Comment: @user21820: Thanks. I'm still going to read Schaum because it's recommended by Cambridge and I'm starting next year. Do you have any personal recommendations for books covering Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Not really. I learnt it on my own, but I think the Wikipedia page is excellent to start with. The diagrams help one to visualize what really the Lagrange multiplier method is doing.